# Locating doubles in a char array (C++/ROOT)

Tags: c++, parsing, extract

I have parsed some XML data, and I want latitude and longitude information. The line I need to parse is this:

> `trkptlat="60.397015"lon="5.32299"`

This is an element in a char array, how can I extract/parse the numbers as doubles? Note that the number precision varies as the data goes on, so I can't solely rely on picking out the column indexes.

Comment: for such an ill formed data you better use regex

Comment: You can try regexp on https://regex101.com/ . This one works on the sample you provided: `lat=\"(\d+\.\d+)\"lon=\"(\d+\.\d+)\"`

Comment: Why don't you use some existing XML parser, such as [expat](https://libexpat.github.io/) or [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) ??

Comment: I am not asking for the char array to be parsed in general. I need it parsed inside C++, as it is part of a program I am writing. The lon and lat information is the last part I need to make my program, but I am horrible at parsing. To reformulate: How, inside C++, can I parse this data so that I am left with the numbers only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using C-Style char arrays as strings. So, my assumptions that you still are on C. Otherwise, you would `std::string`. Ìn C++ there is no jsutification to use a char array instead of a `std::string`.

Please see the C-Style solution:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

    char data[] = "SomeTrashMoreTrashtrkptlat=\"60.397015\"lon=\"5.32299\"MoreTrashMoreTrash";

    char firstDoubleIndicator[] = "trkptlat=\"";
    char secondDoubleIndicator[] = "\"lon=\"";

    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;

    char* startPosition = strstr(data, firstDoubleIndicator);
    if (startPosition) {
        latitude = std::atof(startPosition + std::strlen(firstDoubleIndicator));
    }
    startPosition = strstr(data, secondDoubleIndicator);
    if (startPosition) {
        longitude = std::atof(startPosition + std::strlen(secondDoubleIndicator));
    }
    std::printf("\nlatitude:\t%f\nlongitude:\t%f\n\n", latitude, longitude);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, definitely the solution! A quick note: I don't fully understand that if statement, and how it extracts the right double value... Can you provide some quick documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in numerous ways, warning totally untested code ahead

Using a safe version of sscan with a parameter that looks something like this

```
"\"trkptlat=\"%d\"lon=\"%d\""
```

Be sure to check the return value for length and errors.

Using std::find_first_of with digits and with dots

```
auto start = find_first_of (haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), digits.begin(), digit.end());
auto end = find_first_of (it, haystack.end(), digitsdot.begin(), digitdot.end(), 
 [](char a, char b){ return a != b; });
double lat = atof(start); // somewhere there might be a version that returns how many chars read also.
// check for errors
etc.
```

see further http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/

if your the trusting kind you can take some shortcuts that you know that

```
"trkptlat="
```

will be prepended so you can start at

```
auto start = haystack+preLen;
```